# Debian 10 - OpenSSH-Server How to redirect user login info to a different logins file?

Tags: linux, debian, logging, openssh, sshd

Debian 10 + OPENSSH-SERVER 7.9

I have a remote server that connect to my local server every minutes and in the local server's syslog, every minute I have:

```
Oct 11 18:22:01 localhost systemd[1]: Started Session 26393 of user xxxx. Oct 11 18:22:02 localhost systemd[1]: session-26393.scope: Succeeded.
```

How can I remove this information from syslog and redirect it to, for example, /var/log/sshd.log ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is
Insert in the file /etc/rsyslog.conf the following line

```
auth.info      /var/log/auth.log
```

where /var/log/auth.log can be any file you want

This will redirect the output to this file